# Using LINQ to SQL to perform an update/set

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

So, if I use this query directly or by using `db.ExecuteCommand()` , everything will work fine;

```
update Market..Area set EndDate = NULL where ID = 666 and NID =1 and Code = 36003
```

However, I cant seem to do this in LINQ to SQL, I've tried a few different methods that all seem like they should work, here is an example of one:

```
var s= db.Area.Single(s => s.ID == 666 && s.Code == 36003 && s.NID == 1);
s.EndDate = null;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I dont know what else to try to get this working.

**EDIT**

I am only trying to edit ONE item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a primary key defined on the Area table?
Linq 2 SQL will not make an update to a table without a primary key defined. (And, as far as I can remember, it will fail silently).

Comment: Ah, there is my issue I guess. There is no primary key. So that would mean there is no way at all to do it?

Comment: Yes there is: you can try defining the primary key in the model file (.dbml).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want update more than one item? Even not you can write something like:

```
IQueryable<Area> iArea =
    from s in db.Area
    where s.ID == 666 && s.Code == 36003 && s.NID == 1
    select s;

iArea.ToList().ForEach(item => { item.EndDate = null; });

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: yeah, I will just be updating one item at a time. for some reason that code still doesnt work. It compiles and runs fine, but the action of changing EndDate to null doesnt happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method for doing batch updates. But you can pick some batch extensions from [this blog](http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax appears to be correct. The only other thing I can think of which would be causing the failure is if you are trying to do multiple updates within the same data context.  Try this:

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    var s = db.Area.Single(s => s.ID == 666 && s.Code == 36003 && s.NID == 1);

    s.EndDate = null;
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```