# Not all records update on DataContext.SubmitChanges() (Linq to SQL)

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

In short, one specific record in one table updates while multiple, additional modifications in the same table do not.

`theStat` updates OK upon `.SubmitChanges()`

`statToIncrease` instances do *not* update upon `SubmitChanges()`

Upon watching `.GetChangeSet()`, only one update is being performed. Why aren't any instances of `statToIncrease` updated if modified? Do I have to open a new `DataDataContext` for each update?

The `UserStat` table [has a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339057/using-linq-to-sql-to-perform-an-update-set).

**Maybe another question**

Would it be wise to extend my UserStat class with a method like `.Add(double amountToAdd)`? Another connection would have to be opened, but it would allow me to continue using LINQ-only, right?

```
        using (DataDataContext db = new DataDataContext())
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            var theStat = db.UserStats.FirstOrDefault();

            // tried scoping `statToIncrease` outside of the for loop
            // didn't fix anything
            UserStat statToIncrease = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < vm.stats.Count(); i++)
            {
                statToIncrease = db.UserStats.Where(s => s.ID == i)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                // here, .Property is type float
                statToIncrease.Property += r.NextDouble();
                // here, .Property is type int
                theStat.Property -= 1;
            }

            // create and insert another object
            // this object is inserted correctly

            // right here, .ChangeSet() only has one insert and one update
            // the update is only for `theStat` and not 
            // any modifications to `statToIncrease`
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

**Update**

I found the ugly way of doing this:

```
db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE [UserStat] SET [Value] = {0} WHERE [ID] = {1}, 
    statToIncrease.Value + amount, statToIncrease.ID");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the problem is, but it does seem weird that you are reusing the same variable (`statToIncrease`) and fetching one record at a time. It seems more reasonable to fetch a list of objects, iterate through the list and update them, and then call `SubmitChanges`:

```
using (DataDataContext db = new DataDataContext())
{
    var r = new Random();

    UserStat theStat = db.UserStats.FirstOrDefault();

    List<UserStat> statsToIncrease = 
                               db.
                               UserStats.
                               Where(s => s.ID >= 0 && s.ID < vm.stats.Count()).
                               ToList();

    foreach (UserStat statToIncrease in statsToIncrease)
    {
        statToIncrease.Property += r.NextDouble();
        theStat.Property -= 1;
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: It is odd--maybe I didn't think about it enough before implementing. Basically, `theStat` needs to be decremented by some cumulative value found during multiple `statToIncrease` manipulations. I'll try to re-work it and let you know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach you modified entity explicitly by using :

```
db.UserStats.Attach(statToIncrease, true);
...
db.SubmitChanges();
```

> Do I have to open a new
>   DataDataContext for each update?

No, you haven't.

Comment: No luck with the explicit attachment.

Comment: @David: just an assumption - `statToIncrease` and `theStat` point to the same entity?

Comment: @Alex: Negative. I just commented on a response below because this was more sample code than anything. My actual code does return separate entities on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @David: I tried to reproduce your problem (except for took entities from my `.dbml`). And unfortunatelly I was unable to reproduce this. May be the `magic` in your(suppose) overrded `SubmitChanges` method?

Comment: @Alex: What magic do you mean? I haven't overridden the `.SubmitChanges()` method; are you suggesting that I should?

Comment: @David: nope, you shouldn't if there is no reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
.Where(s => s.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

this will obviously return the same object on each iteration. And I'm guessing that theStat has an ID of 1, which is why it is updated.

Comment: I should've mentioned this was sample code. My real code does return a separate entity to `statToIncrease` each iteration of the loop. It's like `.Where(s => s.ID == i)...`